# ImageView shrinks when image is replaced with another image of same size

Tags: android, android-imageview

I have an imageView in a RelativeLayout and at design time I load from resources a 144x144 png image and everything looks good:

[image]

Now, in code, I take a picture with the camera and crop it to 144x144 and load it into the image view:

```
imageViewMyPicture.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

but now the imageView shrinks:

[image]

Both picture have 100% same size, 144x144 and if I load the second picture into the imageView at design time, the size is loaded normally.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to account for density when creating your scaled bitmap.  Since your `ImageView` has the correct dimensions before setting the new bitmap, in your case you could just use the dimensions of your `ImageView` when scaling the new `Bitmap`...  For example:

I'll assume you're using `Uri`s to retrieve the stored image from the file system after it's been taken.  If you're using `File`s, just use `Uri.fromFile(file)` to get the `Uri`. I normally use an `AsyncTask` to accomplish this since you should do Bitmap processing off of the main thread...here's some sudo code (not in an `AsyncTask` for simplicity, but easily refactored):

```
//Somewhere in your Activity

public void scaleAndSetBitmap(ImageView imageView, Uri uri){
            InputStream stream = null;
            Bitmap bitmap = null;

            try { 
             stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
             bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream, null, options);

              if (image_view != null && bitmap != null) {
                bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bitmap, image_view.getWidth(), image_view.getHeight(), true);
                image_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
              } 
            } catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                return;
            } finally {
                try{
                    stream.close();
                } catch(IOException i){
                    return;
                }
            }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that when you load images you take into account the density of the device you're running on.  You make think you have 144x144, but that could be the raw image file, but when put on a device that is high density it will be rendered at closer to 200x200. Then, when you cut a camera image out as 144x144 you have the raw size, but not the adjusted-for-density size.    The easist way to make sure you get that is to read images using resources:

For example, loading a bitmap with this signature means the app will read the image with the right density and give it the size you need for that device.

```
   selectImg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.drop_device);
```